# How to go full screen on a 'Flutter Web App'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

How can I get rid of white space on top and taskbar at the bottom in my flutter web app? I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

> SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);

I have also tried:

> if (document.documentElement!=null) document.documentElement!.requestFullscreen();

but the latter stopped my app opening on a physical device.

I can only properly check my app after compiling and hosting it first before opening it on my physical device.

[image]

Giving an empty appear with the same colour gives the following result without success:

[image]

Adding an empty bottom navigation stopped the app from opening by giving a grey screen:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Provider.of<CP>(context).primary,
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
    ),
    child: BottomNavigationBar(items: [],),
  ),
```

Comment: Don't add an empty navigationBar, just replace yours or remove the mediaquery

Comment: I never had any bottom navigation bar, removing mediaquery above still leaves an empty bottomnavigationbar, unless you mean something else.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I have a Flutter app which when loaded on a mobile or tablet device's Chrome web browser it shows the web browser Address bar at the top and the Android Navigation bar at the bottom making the available web display area really small. Ideally I would like the app to be shown full screen but don't know if this is possible to achieve using Flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your BottomNavigationBar inside a MediaQuery defining a new bottom padding:

```
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(...),
    );
```

Edit: about the white space at the top, create an "empty" AppBar with the same color as your body background. It's also possible to remove the mediaquery at the top if you want.

Comment: See updated result, it didn't work unfortunately.